# Prime factorisation segmentation error, for Project Euler Prob #3

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, prime-factoring

I'm a 16 year old learning to code in C++. I was recommended to check out some project euler problems as class extras and I'm really enjoying them, however im stuck on problem 3.
The task is to find the highest prime factor of the number n, in my code.
I have researched my problem, and valgrind passes the code.

```
 //
//  7.cpp
//  Thom's Playground
//
//  Created by Thom Foster on 25/01/2015.
//  Find the largest prime factor
//

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Two Routines
//  - Find the highest factor
//  - Out of all those factors, find the highest one which is prime

int main(){

    int HPF;

// FIND THE HIGHEST FACTOR - METHOD 1
    // Initialise the number to find the HPF of , n.
    unsigned long long n = 66761275016;
    // Initialise an array to store the factors, f, with size of n+1, and f[0] is 0
    long long f[n+1];
    f[0] = 0;
    // Divide my nummber (n), by every number up to and including n, where the divisor of n is i
    for (long long i = 1 ; i <= n ; i ++){
        // After each value of i, check if the remainder of n / i is 0.
        if (n % i == 0){
            // If it is, add this to the array of factors, f, in the position f[i], where i is the state of the for loop.
            f[i] = i;
        } // End of if statement
        else {
            f[i] = 0;
        } // End of else
    } // End of for loop

// WHICH OF THOSE FACTORS IS THE HIGHEST PRIME

   for ( long long j = 1 ; j < n+1 ; j++){
       if (f[n-j+1] != 0){
           long long x = f[n-j+1];
           // Start of check prime function
                long long i = 2;
                while ( x % i != 0 && i <= x ){
                    i = i + 1;
                    }
           if (x == i) {
               cout << x << " is prime" << endl;
               return 0;
           }

                else cout << x << " was violated" << endl;
        // end of check prime function
       } // End of check factor if
   } // End of for
} // End of main
```

This works for all numbers below around 6 digits, after that I get a segmentation-fault 11.
Thanks in advance,
Thom

Comment: Just FYI: Usually the loop is only to n/2, not n. Further, you can execution-time optimize it a bit more by making the limits skip the first q and go to n/q where q is the largest prime you want to specifically check.  You then specifically check the lower prime numbers. This adds a bit of complexity to the code, but dramatically decreases execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do all that work; in particular, you don't need to allocate all that memory. Here's a simple algorithm that will quickly factor integers of modest size, including that of Project Euler 3:

```
function factors(n)
    f := 2
    while f * f <= n
        while n % f == 0
            output f
            n := n / f
        f := f + 1
    if n > 1
        output n
```

That outputs the prime factors of *n* in increasing order. It works by trial division, testing each *f* to determine if it is a factor of *n*; when it finds a factor, it outputs it, then reduces *n* to its remaining cofactor. When *f* × *f* exceeds *n*, there can be no remaining prime factors, so *n* is output.

There are faster algorithms for factoring integers, including other variants of trial division. But this algorithm is simple, and always works, and is sufficient in a surprising number of cases.

Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I was considering only doing the factors up to the square root of n, which I think is similiar to what you did in your code. I'll have a look at those other methods, thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
unsigned long long n = 66761275016;
// Initialise an array to store the factors, f, with size of n+1, and f[0] is 0
long long f[n+1];
```

You really cannot allocate about 500 GiB of stack space in RAM in an ordinary PC. You have to rethink your algorithm not to need this humongous array.